# Using RPA shapefile to select Sentinel-2 data

Tags: shapefile, qgis, sentinel

I have a shapefile which came from the Rural Payments Agency which is the complete set of fields for ourfarm.  I would like to use this to find the bounding box for the download. The shapefile is encoded (according to the .prj file) using the British National Grid, GCS_OSGB_1936.

Having downloaded the relevant bit of the sensor data (I am interested in the Sentinel-2 visible and near infra-red so that I can do NDVI and EVI displays) I then want to clip the images to fit the fields.

I tried loading the sensor data and the shapefile, but I must have got the coordinate systems wrong because although I can zoom in on the farm on the sensor data, if I zoom in on the shapefile the sensor data is nowhere to be found.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the CRS of the Vector file. Import in QGIS > Right Click > Set Layer CRS > Select the CRS. Hope This helps!